# Is there any better way to find nth derivative of a function in C?

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I want to write a subroutine that calculates the nth derivative of a function given by the subroutine of the form:

```
double func(double x)
{
    // a mathematical expression representing a smooth curve 
    //returns the value of the function at x      
}
```

i wrote the following subroutine:

```
double nthderive(double (*f)(double),double x0,int n)
{   
   const double delta=1.0e-8;
   double x1=x0 - delta;
   double x2=x0 + delta;
   if(n==0) {
       return f(x0);
   }
   else {
       return (nthderive(f,x2,n-1)-nthderive(f,x1,n-1))/(2*delta);
   }
}
```

Can someone suggest a better algorithm for finding the nth derivative?

Comment: Please note that /2*delta should be /(2*delta)

Comment: What @Bob__ said. I won't be surprised if this is why you keep getting `0.0`

Comment: Thanks it worked , but is there any better way of calculating nth derivative? Thats the main reason i asked this question

Comment: You could eliminate `double h`...

Comment: Well, in order to calculate the derivative, you need the _code_ of the function and the basic differentiation rules. Then you could use some sophisticated parsing to calculate the derivative,  but this's probably gonna be hard. It's much easier to approximate the derivative, which is what your code is doing.

Comment: Numerical differentiation is tricky stuff. You are not going to achieve it with the 'C' equivalent of a recursive one-liner. You would be better off talking to the maths people and they will probably want to know what type of functions you want to differentiate.

Comment: I get your point but I am only allowed to code in C for my course,please tell me is this the best i can do in C without using any other library ?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate a second-order derivative using your code? What do you get?

Comment: Consider what happens when `|x0|` is large like `1e12` and `x0 + /* or - */ 1.0e-8` results in `x0`.  `nthderive()` returns 0.0.

Comment: Yes, it gives correct answer if i change delta value to 1.0e-4.I guess the the delta value needs to be updated after every function call

Comment: "the best i can do in C without using any other library ?"  --> how does code display the result?  What libraries can code use?

Comment: @chux What function did you use and up to which order you are calculating the derivative?

Comment: @chux its just a function and its obvious that i can call it anywhere in my main function and store the value in a variable or display it

Comment: See [2nd derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Limit) equation.  A third and forth, etc equation can be generated.  The point is that the quality of the result is **very dependent on the `delta`** used.  `delta` typically should be _proportional_ to `x0`, not a constant offset.  Unless `x0` is near 0.0, then a constant offset should be used.

Comment: I used the above code to calculate the 2nd derivative of x^3 at x=1.0 and got the answer 5.551115, which is not all that accurate - the correct, exact answer is 6.0.

Comment: @IanAbbott you can try with some other delta value maybe `1.0e-4`

Comment: I know the code does give accurate results every time but please comment only if you have a solution to make it more efficient instead of just poiting out where the result blows up or has a great relative error

Comment: I meant the code doesn't give the best result always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nth derivative can be computed using [Cauchy's integral lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Transform the integral over the path into a "standard integral" (see [Line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)).

Then you can integrate that expression (e.g. with [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)).

If you want to calculate high order derivatives this method will most likely be stable.

Comment: Works only for holomorphic functions.

Comment: That is true. However most functions in "daily" use are holomorphic. (For op: Being holomorphic is equivalent to being differentiable and fullfilling the Cauchy-Rieman equations. Examples of holomorphic functions are: polynomials, exponential function, sin, cos)

Answer (score 0):

Not counting the numerical instability issue, that makes adjustment of `Delta` difficult and precludes the use for high order derivatives (say `n > 3` !), the recursive solution is pretty inefficient, as it takes `2^n` function evaluations, where `n+1` are enough.

Indeed, you compute

```
f' = f(+1) - f(-1)
f'' = f'(+1) - f'(-1) = f(+2) - f(0) - f(0) + f(-2)
f''' = f''(+1) - f''(-1) = f(+3) - f(+1) - f(+1) + f(-1) - f(+1) + f(-1) + f(-1) - f(-3)
...
```

when the Binomial formula tells you

```
f' = f(+1) - f(-1)
f'' = f(+2) - 2f(0) + f(-2)
f''' = f(+3) - 3f(+1) + 3f(-1) - f(-3)
...
```

Comment: thanks but my code gives wrong or slightly off solutions some of the times, apparently this may be due to the fact delta becomes smaller in each step ,can i make it a function of f,x and n to make sure it does not blow up or give wrong results

Comment: @AlokRanjan: where did you see that your Delta decreases ??? Read all the comments, believe them and drop that evil recursive version.